# How to find original size(mm) of the object in the image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, pixel

I have an object in a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHWPS.jpg) with ruler in the background, how can i identify the length and width of this object in terms of the ruler's size in mm.
I have this code that removes some noises in the picture, but not sure what to do next(I was thinking of canny  edge method also)

```
img = cv2.imread('testing.jpg')
img_bw = 255*(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) > 100).astype('uint8')

se1 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
se2 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2,2))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(img_bw, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, se1)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, se2)

mask = np.dstack([mask, mask, mask]) / 255
out = img * mask

cv2.imshow('Output', out)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.imwrite('output.png', out)
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Do you need to read the ruler (say between 30 and 40 mm) automatically to calibrate the conversion from pixels to mm or can you manually draw a line parallel to the ruler (between 30 and 40 mm) and use that 10 mm dimension and corresponding pixel length?

Comment: yes i need to read a ruler and then based on pixels then find length of the object in mm

Comment: But do you need to program a script to read th ruler or will that be done manually to calibrate it?

Comment: yes i need a script to program to read ruler, just finding length between two numbers in a pixels